# Unix to Windows equivalent

Tags: windows, unix, python

I am working on project which is currently on unix platform and
we are going to port that project on windows.

I want to know if there is any windows equivalent to following

```
/proc/cpuinfo 
/proc/loadavg     
/proc/meminfo     
df -T             
/proc/diskstats
```

I also want to get all disk information

```
Filesystem
Size
Serial Number
Check if volume is system volume
```

I tried reading above information [GetVolumeInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364993%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function but I want it to be in pure Python code.

In unix for authentication I used PAM module but its not available in windows I dont find (Tried NTLM but donno is it good way) any    good equivalent to it.

### Strict Note: Only use inbuild API's and Python 2.6.*

Comment: What have you tried? Under Windows, pseudo-devices like /proc do not exist. Therefore, a "pure Python" solution probably is not feasible. One has to use Win32api (or WMI) calls. Example: http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/win32api__GetVolumeInformation_meth.html  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WMI/

Comment: @AxelKemper I tried all that but I want to stick to core python 2.6 utilities only.No other modules are allowed to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/proc` filesystem does not exist on MS windows.

If you want to stick to built-in stuff in Python, you'll have to make to with what you can find from the [os](http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/os.html) and [platform](http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/platform.html) modules.

Alternatively, you can use the built-in [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/ctypes.html) module to call functions from MS windows' `Kernel32.dll`. That way you can extract equivalent information, if available. It would probably be wise to encapsulate this platform specific stuff in a utility module. That would either read `/proc` files or call `Kernel32.dll` functions depending on the value of e.g `platform.system()`.

**Edit**:

For finding information about disks and volumes (windows-speak for filesystems) look at MS info about [local filesystems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364407%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I'd say you could start with [GetLogicalDriveStrings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364975%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), then [GetVolumeInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364993%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Then use other [volume management functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

**Edit2:**

This is an example of using ctypes. I don't have a windows machine available to test it, though. According to the docs, the prototype for GetLogicalDriveStrings is:

```
DWORD WINAPI GetLogicalDriveStrings(
  _In_   DWORD nBufferLength,
  _Out_  LPTSTR lpBuffer
);
```

A `DWORD` is a 32-bit unsigned int. It depends on the platform, but this is usally made with `c_uint` in ctypes. An LPTSTR is a pointer to a memory area to store stuff. We can use `create_string_buffer` to make that. It should work something like this

```
import ctypes

blen = ctypes.c_uint(128)
rv = ctypes.c_uint()
bufs = ctypes.create_string_buffer(128)
rv = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetLogicalDriveStrings(blen, bufs)
if rv.value == 0:
    raise ValueError('GetLogicalDriveStrings returned 0.')
drives = bufs.raw.split('\0')
drvstring = ' '.join(drives)
print drvstring
```

The name `drives` should now reference a list of drive names.

Comment: Can you please explain how to get `volume details (filesystem, serial number, size,)?`

Comment: @Pilot See updated answer.

Comment: @RolandSmith any good reference book on how to use this api calls with  python?

Comment: @VishakhaIngole For starters, look at the ctypes documentation that I linked to. And google for 'ctypes tutorial'.

Comment: Thanks my dear @Rolu..Hope you dont mind me calling Rolu..Ronald